# ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-ec2, python-requests, binance-api-client

actually I'm running a python script on AWS EC2 Ubuntu Server and the script is continuously making a request and after running it for around 14 hours I'm getting the following error Error:

```
 ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

Is there any limit on amount of requests per timeunit (hour, day, second) as a security issue?

If anyone have a solution for it please help me.

Thanks in Advance 
Lakshit

Comment: Don't add these thankful messages and try to ask questions in such a way by which community pay more attention.

Comment: It basically means that something happened with the network connection. Unfortunately, that's the nature of the Internet -- especially after a connection of 14 hours.